# Is this a correct implementation of Single Responsibility Principle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wanted to know if this is a best approach for the Single Responsibility Principle.
The responsibility of this class is Remind users who's accounts are about to expire due to inactivity.

On the 30 Day of inactivity the user gets an email.
On the 45 Day of inactivity the user does not get an email they get disabled.

```
public class AccountReminder
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly ISendExpiringEmail _sendExpiringEmail;

    public AccountReminder(IUnitOfWork uow, ISendExpiringEmail sendExpiringEmail)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _sendExpiringEmail = sendExpiringEmail;
    }

    public void NotifyUpcomingExpiringAccounts()
    {

        // Establish dates
        DateTime accountWarningDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).Date;
        DateTime expirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-45).Date;

        // Retrieve users whose accounts are either about to expire or have already expired
        var users = _uow.UserRepository
            .FindBy(element => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(element.LastLoginDate) == accountWarningDateTime));

        // Send a reminder
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            string htmlBody = "<html xmlns:v=\"urn:...xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\" >";
            htmlBody += "<head><meta http-equiv=...</head>";
            htmlBody += "<body>";

            //following line for only outlook to display image
            htmlBody += "<v:shape id=\>...</v:shape>";
            htmlBody += "<table width='100%'...</table>";
            htmlBody += "</body></html>";

            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/plain");
            LinkedResource pic1 = new LinkedResource("images/Logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            pic1.ContentId = "Logo";
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(pic1);

            _sendExpiringEmail.SendTo(new[] { user.Email }, "EmailSubject", htmlView, plainView);

        }

        DisableExpiringAccounts(expirationDateTime);
    }

    private void DisableExpiringAccounts(DateTime expirationDateTime)
    {
        var expiredUsers = _uow.UserRepository.FindBy(element => element.Enabled && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(element.LastLoginDate) <= expirationDateTime));

        foreach (var user in expiredUsers)
        {
            user.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (expiredUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            _uow.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is a request for a code review and as such would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  If you have a specific *concrete* question about how to solve a particular problem, we'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you interpret *responsibility* on a too high level. This is a common problem. Robert Martin suggests to interpret it [like this](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html):

> The Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) states that each software module should have one and only one reason to change

and also (the same link):

> When you write a software module, you want to make sure that when changes are requested, those changes can only originate from a single person, or rather, a single tightly coupled group of people representing a single narrowly defined business function.

In your example, changes in *business* requirements can concern:

- the logic behind the account expiration mechanism
- the communication channel used to notify users
- the format of the messages

So I can see at least 3 responsibilities here, for at least 3 hierarchies (names are just examples):

- `IAccountExpirationAgent` - the part that verifies if account has expired and disables it if yes, probably only one implementation
- `IAccountExpirationNotifier` - classes that send e-mails (e.g. `AccountExpirationEmailNotifier`), or SMS messages, or whatever
- `IAccountExpirationMessageFormatter` - classes that format messages (e.g. `AccountExpirationMessageHtmlFormatter`, `AccountExpirationMessagePlainTextFormatter`)

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this question should be posted on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) but I still wanted to offer some pointers...

This could be wrong; but the way I interpret Single Responsibility Principal is "one method should have one job."  This prevents us from writing a single 600 line method that does everything and is very cumbersome to maintain.

Smaller, more dedicated (single-responsibility) methods are easier to maintain because they make the larger application more distilled and easy to understand.

If I were to rewrite your class, I would probably do this:

- Split out the email sending functionality
- Split out the HTML body generation; probably send the User model to a Razor view

---

```
public class AccountReminder
{

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly ISendExpiringEmail _sendExpiringEmail;

    public AccountReminder(IUnitOfWork uow, ISendExpiringEmail sendExpiringEmail)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _sendExpiringEmail = sendExpiringEmail;
    }

    public void NotifyUpcomingExpiringAccounts()
    {
        // Establish dates
        DateTime accountWarningDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).Date;
        DateTime expirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-45).Date;

        // Retrieve users whose accounts are either about to expire or have already expired
        var users = _uow.UserRepository
            .FindBy(element => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(element.LastLoginDate) == accountWarningDateTime));

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            SendReminder(user);
        }

        DisableExpiringAccounts(expirationDateTime);
    }

    private void SendReminder(User user)
    {
        // pass a model to a view to generate the HTML
        // the razor implementation should also handle plain-text vs. html mail; you can have two separate templates
        string htmlBody = MyRazorImplementation.GenerateBody(user); 

        _sendExpiringEmail.SendTo(new[] { user.Email }, "EmailSubject", htmlView, plainView);
    }

    private void DisableExpiringAccounts(DateTime expirationDateTime)
    {
        var expiredUsers = _uow.UserRepository.FindBy(element => element.Enabled && (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(element.LastLoginDate) <= expirationDateTime));

        foreach (var user in expiredUsers)
        {
            user.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (expiredUsers.Count > 0)
        {
            _uow.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

}
```